# Folding dialog layout android show empty screen

Tags: android, dialog, folding

I have followed the [Ramotion/folding-cell-android](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android) for fold view animation.

I implement the recycler view instead of list view. i have to open the foldable layout in dialog format but it doesn't working properly.

**My xml file:**

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:minHeight="1000dp"
        android:minWidth="500dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //this view is not visible in dialog
    <test.jinesh.customnavigation.Folding_Cell.FoldingCell
        xmlns:folding-cell="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        folding-cell:additionalFlipsCount="4"
        folding-cell:animationDuration="3000"
        folding-cell:backSideColor="#f4f0ff"
        folding-cell:cameraHeight="30"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/folding_cell"
       >
//this layout have to open in folding format
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/cell_content_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <include layout="@layout/folding_relative" />
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/cell_title_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/event_item" />
                </FrameLayout>
           </test.jinesh.customnavigation.Folding_Cell.FoldingCell>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Dialog window class:

```
  Dialog Foldingdialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
     Foldingdialog.setContentView(convertView);
     ImageView    closebutton=(ImageView) 
     Foldingdialog.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
     FoldingCell  foldable = (FoldingCell) 
     Foldingdialog.findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);

    // on click show dialog
     Foldingdialog.show();
    foldable.toggle(false);
```

folding cell class.java
        [Foldingcell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android/blob/master/folding-cell/src/main/java/com/ramotion/foldingcell/FoldingCell.java)

[image: Output for my code]